# ESXi 6.5 Refusing Connections on 2nd Management Interface

Tags: vsphere, esxi

I need to remotely migrate the management interface on an ESXi 6.5 host. Ideally, I would create the new interface, confirm it works and then delete the old.

I have successfully created the new interface using these commands:

```
esxcli network ip netstack add -N VMManagement

esxcli network ip interface add -i vmk0 -M 00:50:56:67:89:10 -N VMManagement -p mgmt-vm

esxcli network ip interface ipv4 set -i vmk0 -P 1 -t dhcp

esxcli network ip interface tag add -i vmk0 -t Management
```

Here is the outputs of `esxcli network ip interface ipv4 address list -i vmk0 -N VMManagement`

```
Name  IPv4 Address  IPv4 Netmask   IPv4 Broadcast  Address Type  

Gateway      DHCP DNS
----  ------------  -------------  --------------  ------------  -----------  --------
vmk0  10.0.4.27    255.255.255.0  10.0.4.255     DHCP          10.0.4.1      true
```

I can ping vmk0 but it refuses ports 22 and 443. I am able to access ssh/https on the default management interface. I am testing from a host in 10.0.4.0/24 to eliminate routing/firewall variables.

I have tried completely disabling the ESXi firewall as well as running `services.sh restart`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by putting both management interfaces in the default netstack. Initially, I didn't think a single netstack could handle multiple gateways, but this turned out not to be the case.

That said, if anyone does know how to get multiple management interfaces running on separate netstacks, please chime in, as that will be a better answer to this question.